# Easy to use jumper cable to bypass lighting ballast

Tags: connector, home-installation, ballast

I am trying to retrofit 22 high bay LEDs in an armature designed for tungsten halide bulbs (400 W). I understand that I need to cut the capacitor and bypass the ballast.

These fittings are in a hard-to-reach spot (rafters of riding arena), and I am looking for a jumper cable that can be clipped / screwed into place with minimal effort (clamp right through the insulation, no need for cutting / stripping). Hoping to minimize the time I need to spend at the top of a ladder (times 22... it adds up).

I am sure such a cable / connector exists, but I have no idea what it is called, so I can't search for it. I know an "insulation piercing connector" exists for power cables (2/0 AWG); I'm looking for the same thing, but cheaper and in smaller gage (say 12 AWG). I hope somebody here can help identify a suitable solution.

Comment: Not an answer, but are you sure you need to? Some retrofit bulbs are straight retrofit with no modifications needed.

Comment: since you're doing electrical work on an arena, thats a public space so you need to be an electrican to do the work,  so how is it you don't know this already?

Comment: don't use a ladder ... use an elevated work platform

Comment: @Jasen it's a private riding arena... not actually a public space.

Comment: @jsotola - at $350 / day rent, I would like to avoid that since it's coming out of my own pocket.

Comment: @winny - yes, I checked with the supplier. However if you know of LED bulbs that are compatible with ballast, it would be a win. Might be less efficient... which would offset some of the advantages.

Comment: Good. They certainly exist to avoid the very problem you are facing.

Comment: @winny - I really appreciate your pointer. I went looking for alternatives, and I found a bulb that is a little more expensive, and a little less efficient - but which is indeed listed as compatible with ballast. Which makes it "screw in and forget about it" easy - worth it for me. So a big thanks! Not the answer to the question I asked - but the answer I needed. XY problem solved.

Comment: You’re most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given you assertions that this at your home, not at a commercial location.

Search for `IDC tap connector`  be sure to pick one with apropriate agency approvals, and install according to manufacturers instructions.

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed the answer to the question I asked. As I intimated in the comments to the question, @winny pointed out there are some LED lights that are compatible with a ballast; this greatly simplified my problem and is in fact the solution I went with. However, you answered the question I asked, so thank you!